# Hide Google app from devices with small screen/RAM

Tags: android, google-play, screen

I want to make my app unavailable for devices with little amount of RAM and devices with small screen size. I guess small devices are the ones that normally also has the least amount of RAM.

I have not found a way to specific the minimum amount of RAM needed. But can I make it unavailable for small screens by simply setting

```
    <supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="false" />
```

Is is possible to be more specific and set minwidth=480 and minheight=800?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is is possible to be more specific and set minwidth=480 and minheight=800?

No, sorry. Eventually, you might be able to use `android:requiresSmallestWidthDp` for filtering, but the documentation still states that this is not supported.

> I have not found a way to specific the minimum amount of RAM needed

That too is not possible.

Comment: But what will android:smallScreens="false" do? Will this not make it unavailable for small screen (although i can not specify the width/height)?

Comment: @Nissefar: "Will this not make it unavailable for small screen " -- that will work just fine. It is the other things that you requested, that I quoted in my answer, that will not work.